# Is there any audio splitter applications?

Tags: macos, applications, audio

As I know,  there are many audio splitter software like [GoldWave](https://www.goldwave.com/index.php) on the Windows platform. But I cannot find any similar applications for Mac Os.

What I want is an audio splitter which can

1. automatically split the audio file according to its wave, that is, it can recognize the pause automatically;
2. split the audio according to its lyric file.

Do you have any suggestions? I do not like to install a Windows along with OS X to use such software.

Comment: [GarageBand](http://www.apple.com/mac/garageband/) doesn't do what you are looking for?

Comment: @Allan I have GarageBand installed, but I cannot find the way to do the things in the question. Could you post it as an answer if you have any idea? I'll be very appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

[Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/download/mac/) is available for Mac and can do many audio editing functions, though I'm not sure about "split the audio according to its lyric file".

Comment: Thanks! I know Audacity, but I cannot find the way to do the things in the question. Could you explain it in details? I'll be very appreciate!